# Painted glaze with water based primer by mistake

Tags: primer, glazing

I grabbed the wrong can of primer and primed new window glazing with water-based not oil-based. I didn't realize the mistake until we were cleaning up. The glaze had been curing for 2 weeks and was still pretty soft. Do we just wait until it's fully hardened and sand the primer off? Other solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. Are you saying that the glazing is sealed in a way that oil-based primer wouldn't have done and the glazing compound can't dry?

Answer (score 0):

It should dry in time if properly applied. I have not had any issues with water based but some things I still prefer oil based just old school I guess.